# Can I host asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net

If I develop a website in asp.net using visual studio trial version & I have my existing domain which supports asp.net hosting. Do i need to purchase a license copy of .net framework or visual studio in order to lunch my website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. You already have everything you need to launch the site.

The .NET Runtime doesn't require you to purchase anything. If the hosting provider has it installed on the server and offers ASP.NET hosting...you're good to go on that front.

The trial version of Visual Studio also doesn't limit you in this sense. You could've written your ASP.NET code with Notepad and compiled with the .NET SDK that Microsoft distributes freely. It's all the same when it gets served up.

Answer (score 3):

The .NET framework does not require you to buy a license - it is free to download and install, and chances are that your host already has it setup.

As for Visual Studio, it is a development environment - you do not need to install it on the web server.

Once you have developed your site, you can use the built in [Visual Studio publishing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b.aspx) in order to push the site to your host.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is publish the site then configure the site in IIS.